# Trying to create a Symbolic link between Sublime Text 2 and Subl

Tags: linux, arch-linux, symbolic-link, sublime-text-2

As the title says, I'm trying to create a sym link for my Sublime_text launcher, I did:

```
sudo ln -s /path/to/sublime_text /usr/bin/subl
```

and when I `ls /usr/bin` the blue subl link is there. Then I restarted my terminal, and ran `./subl` and also `subl` --- I get the error:

```
bash: subl: command not found
```

I'm not sure what I did wrong, my `echo $PATH` is:

```
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/bin/core_perl
```

Comment: What happens when you run `/path/to/sublime_text`? Is this the correct target file for the symlink?

Answer (score 1):

if `/usr/bin` is in your path (as you point out), you should be able to just type `subl` anywhere from the command line. So this is without the `./`

`./` means "from the current directory". That would only make sense if you were in `/usr/bin`.

Comment: The error message shown (`bash: subl: command not found`) only occurs when *not* typing `./`.

Comment: "Then I restarted my terminal, and ran ./subl and also subl --- I get the error" > seems like het gets the error message regardless of whether he uses ./

Comment: In the first case, it'll probably say `bash: ./subl: No such file or directory`. In any case, this answer won't solve his problem, as he tired both with and without `./`.

Answer (score 1):

I realize this is old, but I thought I'd put in my input if anyone else wander in here, as I had the same problem.

In my case it was a silly mistake of having my command look like:

`ln -s "/home/username/Sublime\ Text\ 2/sublime_text" sublime`

As opposed to without `\` or without `"` Bash isn't very helpful in telling you that your link is bad if you're linking to a file as opposed to a directory.